# laravel 4 install issue when using composer install

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

When I run

> composer.phar install

I get this error almost at the end of the installation, any ideas?

Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files

Warning: Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home/belendez/public_html/laravel/artisan on line 46

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/belendez/public_html/laravel/artisan on line 46
Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error

[image]

I look into the suggested link and it appears that somehow in the middle of the installation it changes from 5.3 to 5.2! If I try to start installation using 5.2 it returns right a way: class 'Phar' not found. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the composer.json in your directory when you execute the command? Are you using Linux? (although this is not that important). Have you check this link http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

Comment: If you are using older php like 5.2 then this could be a problem by the way but looking at your screenshot it looks like your using php 5.3 which should not be a problem. This question by the way is like a duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975613/laravel-running-artisan-gives-me-unexpected-character-in-input-error

Comment: Yes I have the composer.json in the same directory, using Linux, yes I check getcomposer.org.. yes I´m using php 5.3.23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that issuing only a `php` command will pick up another version of the interpreter. Try to change all the references to `php` in your `composer.phar` file to the one you want actually to be executed (in your case it seems `/opt/php53/bin/php`).

You can confirm that by simply launching a `php -v` directly from the command line to see what version your server will pick up

Comment: Strange, that's still not helping me. Same error appears even using an absolute path to php 5.4, such as /usr/local/bin/php54 ../composer.phar install. Maybe I have to set the path in env?