# Laravel 4 - Composer Install fails every time, even though I'm using PHP 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I'm running into issues installing Laravel 4... I am following the instructions posted here:

http://badubizzle.blogspot.com/2013/01/setting-up-laravel-4-on-webfaction.html

My host allows multiple versions of PHP to run at the same time, so running the command `php` will run php 5.2.17 on whatever you specify next.  I know you need greater than php 5.3 to run Laravel 4, so I am using php 5.4 to do so.  I can either specifically type `php54` to run the command under php 5.4, or an alias can be made in the .bash_profile to do so just when typing php, which is what I did.

Now, when I run the command `php -v`, I get the following:

```
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Jul 24 2013 07:46:20) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.2.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by ionCube Ltd.
```

The reason I did that was because when using composer, it seems that a lot of the commands it runs, it finds in the laravel files that are downloaded, and they all start with `php`, instead of `php54`, so I figured by making the alias, I should be fine, right?  Wrong.

When I run this line:

```
php ~/composer.phar install
```

The system gets a bunch of files (like it should), and then it gets to this error:

```
Warning: Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home/apps/laravel-master/artisan on line 46

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/apps/laravel-master/artisan on line 46
Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error
```

When I research this error, everything I see says that it's an error of not running a high enough PHP version, and that you need to run `php54` or something.  I am doing that, and I'm still getting this error!  Any ideas here?  This REALLY has me stumped and I'm getting super frustrated.  I would really appreciate any help anyone can offer!!

**EDIT**

I have tried following Laravel's documentation and have run into the same issue once I run the `composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist` command - it runs for a while, and then gets to the parse error.  I really have no idea what's wrong here!

Comment: Those instructions look old - why dont you start again and just use the official installation docs here - it might solve your problem - http://four.laravel.com/docs/installation

Comment: I've tried that method multiple times, which is why I was branching out to try and find other solutions... Nothing I've tried is working.

Comment: @Laurence can't even open the link provided. is it the same as https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation

Comment: I would recommend you start over with a new installation of laravel using the correct version and requirements, maybe you have some php configs. Try using a documentation that isn't more then 4 years old, it might help.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment directly on thinkers Answer (not enough rep it seems), but I can say that the answer he linked to isn't just about an alias and it works for me.

open composer.json, and you'll see that it's trying to run the php command during post-install, and it's just using the regular php, something like:

```
php artisan optimize
```

You need to change that to something like:

```
/opt/php54/bin/php artisan optimize
```

Or whatever the path is. Composer, when reading the json file, doesn't really seem to care what your alias is. At least it didn't on the shared server I installed Laravel on.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a common problem on shared hosting when paths are not set properly. I already posted a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995549/laravel-4-install-issue-when-using-composer-install/), maybe it works for you also.

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help, but did you not see that when I run `php -v` my server says I'm running 5.4?  Your solution is one of many that have said that, and haven't helped

Comment: yes, i've seen thah `php -v` is an alias to `php54`, but inside the composer.phar the php interpeter will be called multiple times, and probably the bash alias is not seen from inside it. Have you tried it or are you just guessing?