# Laravel Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) Shared Server

Tags: php, laravel

I'm hosting my system in laravel on Locaweb, a shared server. However, when migrating my hosting plan, I am getting this error when trying to use "php artisan...". Using info.php to show my php version it appears that it is 7.3.28. However, when I type php -v in the terminal inside public_html, it shows me that it is 5.2.

```
Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home/storage/a/b7/b3/reciclaoleovegetal/public_html/public/index.php on line 52

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/storage/a/b7/b3/reciclaoleovegetal/public_html/public/index.php on line 52
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: running artisan gives me "Unexpected character in input" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975613/laravel-running-artisan-gives-me-unexpected-character-in-input-error)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156251/unexpected-character-in-input-ascii-92-state-1)

Answer (score 1):

Hy,

I had the same issue, every time I run `artisan`.

It seems the command `php` is linked to the wrong php version. If you run artisan with the correct php version, the error should disappear.

On my provider the command was `/usr/bin/php8.1-cli artisan`, but I do not know the location of the php script on Locaweb.

A good starting point would be to see if there is a php file in the same directory.
Simply run `ls /usr/bin/ -Al | grep php` to get a list of all files in `/usr/bin/` wiht *php* in the file name.
If you find a file (let's say `php8.1`) you then can run artisan with `/usr/bin/php8.1 artisan`